# Why does my Spark application's web UI not show DAG visualization but History Server does?

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA to develop and run my Spark application. I have this set up in `conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:/home/user/spark-2.2.0/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    file:/home/user/spark-2.2.0/spark-events
```

In my application, I also have this:

```
val session = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("MySparkApp")
    .master("spark://user:7077")
    .config("spark.jars", "target/mysparkapp.jar")
    .config("spark.eventLog.enabled","true")
    .config("spark.eventLog.dir","file:/home/user/spark-2.2.0/spark-events")
    .config("spark.history.fs.logDirectory","file:/home/user/spark-2.2.0/spark-events")
    .getOrCreate()
```

I can see DAG visualization in Spark History Server after the application finished. However, there is no DAG visualization shown in spark web ui. Any idea why this happened?

I am using Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 57.0.1 (64-bit). And here is the screenshot of my history server:

[image]

And my WEB UI:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use web UI of your Spark application at 4040 (not Spark Standalone's web UI)

You use Spark Standalone (judging from `.master("spark://user:7077")`) and the screenshot comes from the web UI of Spark Standalone that you may have accessed at `http://user:8080` (used `user` for the hostname from your code in `master`).

`localhost:8080` has never displayed DAG visualizations of any Spark application. It has always been used for Spark Standalone's web UI. You could have used `localhost:18080` instead, i.e. with the `1` before `8080`.

The web UI of your Spark application (where you can find DAG visualization) is by default available at 4040 (or the following ports if that is already taken). That however depends on the cluster deployment environment and deploy mode.

What's also important is that `localhost:4040` is only available when a Spark application is up and running. Right after the Spark application has finished, the web UI is gone and no longer accessible.

Comment: you mean to say. the dag will not be available for spark standalone?

Comment: That's right. Spark Standalone's UI is for applications managed by the cluster manager while web UI of a Spark application can show what this app does, incl. DAGs.